# Equinox Project Migrate Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-core

I am currently learning to create rest api's with asp.net core. 
I found a project on GitHub which implements some technologies im interested in.
https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject

Now I'm trying to setup this project. 
My main problem is to `add migrations` or to `update database`.

When i try `Add-Migration init -Context EquinoxContext` i get this error message:

> Unable to create an object of type 'EquinoxContext'. For the different
>   patterns supported at design time, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I found a solution that worked but i didnt think that is the way to go because the project originally didnt did so.

I've added the dbcontext files in the ConfigureServices method of the `startup.cs` in `Equniox.Services.Api`

```
        services.AddDbContext<EquinoxContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Equinox.Infra.Data")));

        services.AddDbContext<EventStoreSQLContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Equinox.Infra.Data")));
```

If I use the `GenerateDataBase.sql` from the project files the project works well but i want to understand how to build the database from code base.

Is there an other command to create the migrations and then updaten the database?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
Change 
services.AddScoped<'EquinoxContext'>(); by
 services.AddDbContext <'EquinoxContext'> ();

Y
services.AddScoped<'EventStoreSQLContext'>();
by
services.AddDbContext<'EventStoreSQLContext'>();

in

NativeInjectorBootStrapper.cs

**Console:**

Start project: Api

Focus project: Data